# Drawing onto a text widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering whether it is possible to use some of the tkinter canvas drawing methods on a text widget. Ideally I would have the text widget placed onto the canvas so that I can draw onto the canvas and make it look like it shows up on the text widget.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to draw over or into a tkinter `Text` widget. You can,  however, add text to a canvas with the [create_text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method) method and draw over that.

Comment: Is it then possible to make it somewhat transparent so that I can put the widget over a canvas and then when I draw onto the canvas I can somewhat see what's both the text in the text widget and the drawing on the canvas?