# Draw line on text widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

So, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117096/8105907), this code should be working. I want to display the green line on top of the text widget, but the line is behind it.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
root.configure(bg='#252525', relief=SOLID, bd=2)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=100, bg='white')
canvas.place(x=50, y=50, width=200, height=100)

text = Text(root)
text.place(x=50, y=70, width=200, height=60)
text.config(bg='gray')

canvas.create_line(170, 0, 170, 700, width='5', fill='green')
mainloop()
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the answer you linked to.  The suggestion there was to put the text directly on the canvas (via `create_text`), so that you can draw over it, NOT as a `Text()` widget.

Comment: So, there's no way to draw over text widgets, apparently. :(

Comment: Correct, there is no way to draw over a text widget.